# it has errors in catch blocks below the catch (Exception)

Tags: c#

I'm beginner in csharp and newly started to coding with it.
I have written a code but it has errors in catch blocks below the catch (Exception).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result;
        int x = 5;
        int y;

        try
        {
            y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            result = x / y;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured.");
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }
        catch (FormatException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid input!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Apart from a random `continue;` that doesn't belong here, what errors do you get?

Comment: it shows me this "ErrorCS0160 A previous catch clause already catches all exceptions of this or of a super type ('Exception') " @UnholySheep

Comment: has other said remove 'continue' and first catch

Comment: As the error says, the first `catch (Exception)` already catches all exceptions, so none of the latter ones will ever be hit. You presumably want to move it to be the last `catch` before the `finally`

Comment: Your first catch clause catches all exceptions derived fro `Exception` so the following catch clauses will never be executed and are completely useless. Move the first exception to the end as last catch clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order  of the `catch` clauses is important because they are examined in order. Catch the more specific exceptions before the less specific ones. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

In your code, move the Catch(Exception) block before the finally () block so it gets evaluated last.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put return keyword in finally block 
It's not correct

```
finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid name and age ");
            }
```